# Android kernel compilation error

Tags: android, linux, kernel, android-source

I am trying to compile android kernel (cyanogen) for Samsung Galaxy mini , according to these [instructions](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Building_Kernel_from_source):

I am using CM-7.

I performed these steps:

1. Download kernel source code.
2. Configure the build :

   ```
   adb pull /proc/config.gz /home/user_name/android/kernel/cm-kernel/config.gz 
   cat config.gz | gunzip > .config 
   make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=$CCOMPILER menuconfig
   ```
3. Make the build:

   ```
    make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=$CCOMPILER -j4
   ```

After this kernel starts compiling and everything works fine but then it throws an error, here is the output of the terminal:

```
 CC [M]  drivers/gpio/wm8994-gpio.o
 LD [M]  sound/usb/misc/snd-ua101.o
 LD [M]  sound/usb/snd-usb-audio.o
 LD [M]  sound/usb/snd-usbmidi-lib.o
 CC [M]  drivers/gpio/sch_gpio.o
 CC [M]  drivers/gpio/rdc321x-gpio.o
 LD      fs/nfs_common/built-in.o
 CC [M]  fs/nfs_common/nfsacl.o
 CC [M]  fs/nfs/direct.o
 CC      net/socket.o
 CC [M]  drivers/gpio/janz-ttl.o
 LD [M]  fs/nfs_common/nfs_acl.o
  drivers/gpio/janz-ttl.c: In function 'ttl_set_value':
  drivers/gpio/janz-ttl.c:107: error: implicit declaration of function 'iowrite16be'
  make[2]: *** [drivers/gpio/janz-ttl.o] Error 1
  make[1]: *** [drivers/gpio] Error 2
  make: *** [drivers] Error 2
  make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  CC [M]  fs/nfs/pagelist.o   
  fs/nfs/direct.c: In function 'nfs_direct_read_schedule_segment':
  fs/nfs/direct.c:364: warning: format '%zu' expects type 'size_t', but argument 5 has type 'unsigned int'
  fs/nfs/direct.c: In function 'nfs_direct_write_schedule_segment':
  fs/nfs/direct.c:799: warning: format '%zu' expects type 'size_t', but argument 5 has type 'unsigned int'
  fs/nfs/direct.c: In function 'nfs_file_direct_read':
  fs/nfs/direct.c:928: warning: format '%zd' expects type 'signed size_t', but argument 4 has type 'size_t'
  fs/nfs/direct.c: In function 'nfs_file_direct_write':
  fs/nfs/direct.c:982: warning: format '%zd' expects type 'signed size_t', but argument 4 has type 'size_t'
 CC      net/802/p8022.o
 CC [M]  fs/nfs/proc.o
 CC      net/802/psnap.o
 CC      net/802/tr.o
 CC [M]  fs/nfs/read.o
 CC      net/8021q/vlan_core.o
 CC [M]  net/8021q/vlan.o
 CC      net/802/fc.o
 CC [M]  fs/nfs/symlink.o
 CC      net/802/fddi.o
 CC [M]  net/8021q/vlan_dev.o
 CC [M]  fs/nfs/unlink.o
```

If anyone can please tell how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including this header

```
#include<asm/io.h>
```

If it doesn't work then look at this for all the definitions of `iowrite16be`
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=iowrite16be

Choose the appropriate header based on your architecture.

**EDIT** : Generally `implicit declaration of function xyz()` is a warning. May be in your system its been forced to an error with `-Werror-implicit-function-declaration`. You can search for this in your build structure and try to take it off ( Though its **not** a good practice, but anyways you can do it, if you want the work done ) But if `iowrite16be` is really missing, then even this method wont help you from the linker's wrath.

Comment: including the header #include<asm/io.h> didn't fix the error, but i will try the remaining headers, thanks for your response.

Comment: removing -Werror-implicit-function-declaration from the makefile fixed the error, thanks for your continuous help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also just add the definition yourself:

```
void iowrite16be(u8 shadow, void __iomem* port);
```

Just add it right above the ttl_set_value() function.